# How to initialize dynamicly array from struct C++

Tags: c++, struct, compiler-errors, initialization, function-definition

I have an assignment to write a function that dynamicly initialize an array from struct that is in the header file. and for some resone I am keep getting the same error "uninitialized local variable 'columnData' used
this is the header file

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H
#define QUEUE_H


/* a queue contains positive integer values. */
typedef struct queue
{
    int arraySize;
    int* column;
} queue;

void initQueue(queue* q, unsigned int size);
void cleanQueue(queue* q);

void enqueue(queue* q, unsigned int newValue);
int dequeue(queue* q); // return element in top of queue, or -1 if empty

#endif /* QUEUE_H */
```

this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "queue.h"

int main()
{
    queue* columnData;
    unsigned int size = 0;
    std::cout << "Please enter column size: ";
    std::cin >> size;
    initQueue(columnData, size);
    printf("%d", &columnData->column[0]);

}

void initQueue(queue* q, unsigned int size) {
    q->column = new int[size];
    q->column[0] = 5;
}

void cleanQueue(queue* q) {

}

void enqueue(queue* q, unsigned int newValue) {

}

int dequeue(queue* q) {
    return 1;
}
```

If someone can help me it will be great.

Comment: You never assign `columnData` a value in `main`, then you read that uninitialized value to pass to a function. You might want to have `queue columnData` and pass it as `&columnData` to your functions. Better would be to take all those functions and make them members of `queue`.

Answer (score 1):

You declared an uninitialized pointer

```
queue* columnData;
```

that has an indeterminate value. So calling the function `initQueue`

```
initQueue(columnData, size);
```

invokes undefined behavior because within the function this pointer is dereferenced.

```
q->column = new int[size];
q->column[0] = 5;
```

Also the function does not set the data member `arraySize`.

You need in main to declare an object of the type `queue`

```
queue columnData;
```

and call the function like

```
initQueue( &columnData, size);
```

and within the function you have to set also the data member `arraySize` like

```
columnData->arraySize = size;
```

Pay attention to that this call

```
printf("%d", &columnData->column[0]);
```

is also wrong. You are trying to output a pointer using the incorrect conversion specifier `%d`.

After changing the declaration of the object `columnData` shown above the call of `printf` will look like

```
printf("%d", columnData.column[0]);
```

Though it will be more consistent to use the overloaded operator <<.